# Can we combine Keystone JS with Angular?

Tags: angular, keystonejs

I recently got to know about the CMS tool Keystone and was going through their example and some tutorials online. Most of the tutorials used HandleBars for the view. I'm familiar with Angular 2 and want to use Angular for the view.

My initial approach was to create a Keystone JS project and then create a Angular 2 app inside it using angular cli. And set the build target for angular app to public folder of the Keystone JS project. But I'm missing the link in the Keystone JS where to point to look for the Angular build generated files.

If anyone has worked on it, please let me know on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating your Angular app separately from your Keystone app.

You can then set up REST end points with Keystone and use them in your Angular app to retrieve the data. Instead of rendering templates from your views (route controllers) you can send your data in the response using res.send() or using Keystone middleware: res.apiResponse().

If you really want Keystone and Angular in the same project then you could build the app to the public folder, as you say, and then instead of rendering a template (handlebars, etc.) from your root ('/') route you could serve the index.html file from your public folder.

However, this could get messy so I would suggest having the two separate.

Comment: I recommend this answer. This makes your project more easy to work with. You can even start another website and retrieve data over there too. If you had 2 websites pulling data from 1 backend, it wouldn't make sense anymore to keep it in a single project. I guess the correct term is "more modular"?

Comment: @Steve Holgado , if ill be creating the app seprate from the keystone app when it comes to hosting the app to cloud do i also need to host them seperately ? thanks

Comment: @JhonCaylog if your app is a client-rendered SPA or a statically generated site then you can host this separately on a service like AWS S3 or even GitHub pages. Your Keystone app and database will need a server(s) though.

Comment: yeah its a SPA app

Comment: so the ideal way is to host them seperately ?

Comment: @JhonCaylog yes, I think it would be good to take advantage of S3, Netlify or similar to serve your SPA. This way, you can reduce the load that your server has to handle. Plus you can deploy your backend and frontend independently if one changes.

Comment: @SteveHolgado , thank you for your answer sir , appreciated it